# Concatenating DataFrames with similar and disjoint columns

Tags: python, join, dataframe, concatenation

Problem is simplified for ease of discussion.

Take 3 dataframes with similar and disjoint columns, but the same column values. How does one concatenate them in such a way that there are no repeated columns, all unique columns are retained (i.e. not doing an inner join), and new rows are not created if column values are the same?

Individual dataframes:

df1:

```
    a  b  c
0   1  2  3
1  11 22 33
```

df2:

```
    b  c  d
0   2  3  4
1  22 33 44
```

df3:

```
    c  d  e
0   3  4  5
1  33 44 55
```

Desired output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   4   5
1  11  22  33  44  55
```

However, simply using

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```

includes duplicate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
Using `concat` + `groupby` -

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], 1).groupby(axis=1, level=0).first()

    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   4   5
1  11  22  33  44  55
```

---

**Option 2**
`merge` -

```
df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)

    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   4   5
1  11  22  33  44  55
```

In general, for `n` dataframes, if you have a list of them, you can perform an n-way merge with a loop -

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

```
df = df_list[0]

for d in df_list[1:]:
    df = df.merge(d)

df
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   2   3   4   5
1  11  22  33  44  55
```

Comment: I have 6 dataframes, so for code clarity I would like to avoid merges. I like this groupby option!

Comment: @Lisle Ah, I thought that might be the case. I did add a general merge option, but in the end the groupby operation is the best, if the values are the same across columns.